# Tree of groups $(\mathcal{G},T)$

Tags: group-actions, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be act on $\Gamma$ with a fundamental domain $T$ where $T$ is tree. We construct *tree of groups* $(\mathcal{G},T)$ with the following structure:
$$\text{for every } v\in V(T),\,\,G_v=\operatorname{Stab}_G(v) $$

$$\text{for every } e\in E(T),\,\,G_e=\operatorname{Stab}_G(e) $$

Assume that $G_T$ is the direct limit of the system $(\mathcal{G},T)$. With using the universal property of the definition of the direct limit, we get the map $\phi\colon G_T\mapsto G$.

Now my question is:

If $\Gamma$ is connected, then why can we conclude that $\phi$ is a surjective map?

Comment: Please note the proper use of \text{} and \operatorname{} in my edits to this question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the statement of Lemma 4 in Chapter 4.1 of Serre's Trees book. In terms of your specific problem in the lemma is a little too general and you can set $Y=T$. However, the previous Lemma 2 which is being generalized is too specific. This book is a beautiful read and strongly recommended!

Note that this is an answer to your question in terms of Bass-Serre-Theory. That is also why Lee Mosher's answer is incorrect, since in his example there *exists no* fundamental domain.

Comment: I added a comment to my answer addressing your point. The fundamental domain is usually defined so as to exist in broader contexts than you claim, and it is as useful in those broader contexts as it is in the narrow context in which you construe the OP's question.

Comment: I did not claim anything. That is why I pointed out the context of Bass-Serre-Theory, which uses the definition: Let $G$ act on the graph $X$, then a fundamental domain of $X\operatorname{mod} G$ is a subgraph $T$ of $X$, s.t. the composition $T \to G\backslash X$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score -1):

We cannot conclude that $\phi$ is surjective, because it is not true in general. Here is a counterexample.

- $\Gamma = \mathbb{R}$ with vertex set $\mathbb{Z}$.
- $G = \mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$ by translation.
- $T = [0,1]$ is a fundamental domain.

The stabilizer of each vertex $0$ and $1$ of $T$ is trivial, and the stablizer of the unique edge $[0,1]$ in $T$ is trivial. So $G_T$ is the trivial group. There is no map from the trivial group onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The map $T\to G\backslash \Gamma$ is no isomorphism (the latter is no tree), hence $T$ is not considered a fundamental domain.

Comment: @Dan: I see that you are using the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain which requires the fundamental domain to contain exactly one point from each orbit. However, the standard definition used by geometric group theorists is broader, for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalDomain.html which requires a fundamental domain $D$ to be closed, to intersect each orbit in at least one point, and so that $D \cap g \cdot D$ have empty interior for each nontrivial group element g. The OP could, perhaps, advise us of which definition is intended.

Comment: Talking about graphs of groups (Bass-Serre-Theory) it would be reasonable to use the definition which was developed for this theory. I am aware of the topologists notion of a fundamental domain, that is why I wrote "considered" in my original comment, because it was meant to be contextual.

Comment: @Dan: It's certainly very interesting to consider the subclass of fundamental domains which are defined as you defined them. I just wanted to let you know that nowadays, people who work with Bass-Serre theory have gravitated towards the broader definition of fundamental domain because it is so useful.

Comment: Thanks for that notice. Do you have some references for this? I am curious because the big results seem to fail then (as we see in this answer). So how would you use Bass-Serre-Theory then?

Comment: @Dan: A good reference is the paper by Scott and Wall, "Topological methods in group theory. Homological group theory (Proc. Sympos., Durham, 1977), pp. 137–203, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 36, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge-New York, 1979.

Comment: Just as an example, one can write down a presentation for $G$, with additional generators caled "stable letters" to account for vertices of $T$ in the same $G$-orbit, and with additional relators involving the stable letters. One can also prove many algebraic properties of $G$ depending on how it acts on $T$.